# 2002 Taurus slow- charging the battery

Tags: battery, taurus

I took my dead car battery to Bulldog Battery. They are charging my battery slowly over 2 days. I did not know that it took that long to charge a battery. Any insights as to why so long to charge my batterY?

Comment: Do you know why the battery was dead? Was your Taurus not charging the battery? New motorcycle batteries take ~24 hours to fully charge. I imagine car batteries take at least 24 hours to fully charge.

Answer (score 1):

the faster you charge the battery the faster it heats up. if you feed it 100amps for one hour it may boil the water and sulfuric acid inside which creates hydrogen gas, you dont want hydrogen gas think Hindenburg. slow charging at 2amps for 20 hours is the same amount of power/electricity/watts going in but at a much slower rate that wont boil stuff.

giving a batter too much juice too quick = boom.